# Show hide table tr skipping the first tr of the table ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of the button i want to show hide the tr of the tables.But i want to skip the first tr of the table that will we always visible.I have to show hide the all other tr of the table how can we do this in jquery

**Table**

```
<table id="tableid">
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you made *any* effort at all? You've got 1381 rep (as I write), you should know we expect to see your own attempts.

Comment: there will be one button to hide all tr or each tr will have a button to hide that tr ?

Comment: with single button i have to do show and hide

Comment: @DavidThomas i am new in this Jquery and i have exp of Android that's why i posted simple question

Comment: The 'simple question' isn't the problem, it's the lack of any attempt at a solution, or research undertaken, that concerns me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, I haven't checked it but it should work fine:

```
<table id="tableid">
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
</table>

<button class="click">Hide</button>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.click').click(function() {
            if ($('#tableid tr:last-child').is(':visible') === true) {
                $('#tableid tr:not(:first-child)').hide();
                $(this).text('Show');
            } else {
                $('#tableid tr:not(:first-child)').show();
                $(this).text('Hide');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyNNT/5/) with a working example here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

### HTML:

```
<table id="tableid">
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
</table>

<input id="hide" type="button" value="Hide"/>
```

### JQUERY:

```
   $("#hide").click(function(){

    $('table#tableid > tbody > tr').not(':first').hide();

})
```

you can use `toggle()` for **hide/show** effect:

```
$('table#tableid > tbody > tr').not(':first').toggle("show");
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/Kh7U9/2)

Comment: how i will decide now i have to show the tr i have on button .Basically i was trying to get the some feature of toggle

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switching approach:

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableid">
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
<p><button id="showHide">Hide Rows</button></p>
```

**JQuery**

```
$stat = 1;
$("#showHide").click(
    function()
    {
        if($stat == 1)
        {
            $('#tableid tr:not(:first-child)').hide();
            $(this).text("Show Rows");
            $stat = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#tableid tr:not(:first-child)').show();
            $(this).text("Hide Rows");
            $stat = 1;
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyLcb/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `toggle()`:

```
// select the 'tr' that is/are the ':first-child' of its parent,
// use 'on()' to bind the click event-handler:
$('#tableid tr:first-child').on('click', function(){
    // '$(this)' is the jQuery wrapped node upon which the click occurred,
    // use 'nextAll()' to find all subsequent sibling 'tr' elements,
    // 'toggle()' (show, if they're hidden; hide if they're shown):
    $(this).nextAll().toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NJHZ7/1/).

To use plain JavaScript, you could simply use the `style` attribute:

```
function toggleSiblings (){
    // 'this' is the clicked element:
    var target = this;

    // continue the loop while there is a nextElementSibling:
    while (target.nextElementSibling) {
        // set the 'display' to 'table-row' if it's currently 'none',
        // set it to 'none' if it's *not* currently 'none':
        target.nextElementSibling.style.display = target.nextElementSibling.style.display === 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';
        // point the 'target' node-reference to the nextElementSibling, and continue:
        target = target.nextElementSibling;
    }
}
// using 'document.querySelector()' to find the first element that is a 'tr'
// and is the ':first-child' of its parent:
var firstChild = document.querySelector('tr:first-child');

// using addEventListener() to bind event-handling:
firstChild.addEventListener('click', toggleSiblings);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NJHZ7/2/).

Or you could even use CSS:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="firstRowToggle" />
<table id="tableid">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="firstRowToggle">a</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the CSS:

```
/* 'tr' elements that are general-siblings of the 'tr:first-child',
   that are teh child of a 'table' element which is the adjacent-sibling
   of the element with the given 'id' */
#firstRowToggle + table tr:first-child ~ tr {
    /* display as normal */
    display: table-row;
}

/* if the checkbox is checked, then the non-first-child 'tr' elements
   are set to be hidden/not-displayed */
#firstRowToggle:checked + table tr:first-child ~ tr {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NJHZ7/3/).